# Create a custom prompt box and wait till the use give input in React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, user-interaction

I am using React JS and want to use Material UI popover component for taking user input. I want it to work a similar way the browser window prompt box does, it waits until the user gives input. And returns the entered text from where it was called. I don't know how to implement this. I didn't find any useful articles or answers related to this.

Any answers or suggestions would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `timeoutRef` that will run after user stop typing for amount of time

```
const timeoutRef = useRef(null)

const handleChange = e => {
     if (timeoutRef.current) clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
     timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => showOptions(e.target.value), 1000) 
  }


<Input onChange={handleChange} />
```

Dont sure what exactly you wanna achieve with `showOptions` so didn't elaborate on that part